# " expects type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'void "

Tags: c

Code:

```
printf( "%s", __builtin_return_address(0));
```

Warning :

> format '%s' expects type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'void

**Side Notes** I have been experimenting with some register keywords.. Perhaps the command above would have provided some info if it had worked.

Comment: @Rajeshkumar Then *UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR* will occur. Bad advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print the address you need the appropriate specifier,

```
printf("%p\n", __builtin_return_address(0));
```

should work.

Answer (score 4):

According to [gcc.gnu.org](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html), syntax of function:

```
void * __builtin_return_address (unsigned int level)
```

function return the `void*`. So, use `%p` format specifier instead of `%s`.